# WM_ERASEBKGND not followed by WM_PAINT

Tags: windows, sdk, gdi, message

My app is getting a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message which is *not* followed by a `WM_PAINT` message. Naturally enough my application erases the background, and then just sits there with a blank window.

I am running under Vista, but it happens under XP as well. I am pretty sure it is my fault, but what could I be doing so that Windows does not behave?

I am fairly sure about the messages as I am using Spy++ to watch. This is a C app compiled under MSVC 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `BeginPaint` / `EndPaint` in your `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler.